# Shell script breaks with grep

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Sorry if this a basic/stupid question.
I have no experience in shell scripting but am keen to learn and develop.

I want to create a script that reads a file, extracts an IP address from one line, extracts a port number from another line and sends them both toa a variable so I can telnet.

My file looks kinda like this;

```
Server_1_ip=192.168.1.1
Server_2_ip=192.168.1.2

Server_port=7777
```

I want to get the IP only of server_1
And the port.

What I have now is;

```
Cat file.txt | while read line; do
my_ip="(grep -oE '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' <<< "$line")"
echo "$my_ip"
done < file.txt
```

This works but how do I specify `server_1_ip`?

Next I did the same thing to find the port but somehow the port doesn't show, instead it shows "server_port" and not the number behind it

Do i need to cat twice or can I combine the searches? And why does it pass the IP to variable but not the port?

Many thanks in advance for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awk may be a better fit:

```
awk -F"=" '$1=="Server_1_ip"{sip=$2}$1=="Server_port"{sport=$2}END{print sip, sport}' yourfile
```

This awk says:

1. Split each row into columns delimited by an equal sign: `-F"="`
2. If the first column has the string `"Server_1_ip"` then store the value in the second column to awk variable `sip`: `$1=="Server_1_ip"{sip=$2}`
3. If the first column as the string `"Server_port"` then store the value in the second column to awk variable `sport`: `$1=="Server_port"{sport=$2}`
4. Once the entire file has been processed, then print out the value in the two variables: `END{print sip, sport}`

Comment: An explanation of your answer would greatly help the OP develop. Code alone doesn't teach as well.

Comment: Many thanks JNevill for taking the time to answer me. Sadly the command doesn't print out anything. I cat my file | awk and send to a text file to see results. But the file is empty and nothing is shown on screen either.

Comment: Sorry it long, broken phone. I did manage to make it work. Had to separate into two searches, pass it to sed to remove some extra characters. Learned that awk variables are not passed to she'll so I set the awk itself in a variable that i later echo. Had to work and tweak but def got it to work. Many thanks!

Comment: Oh great! I was trying to remember answering this, but I have no recollection. I'll add some details as @JRFerguson recommended (I always do with awk, but I must have been in a hurry and just dropped this answer and ran).

Comment: @JNevill +1 for the follow-up :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='=' read key value; do
        case "$key" in
        Server_1_ip) target_ip="$value";;
        Server_port) target_port="$value";;
        esac
done < input
```

This is almost certainly *not* the appropriate solution, since it requires you to statically define the string `Server_1_ip`, but it's not entirely clear what you are trying to do.   You could `eval` the lines, but that is risky.

How exactly you want to determine the host name to match will greatly influence the desired solution.  Perhaps you just want something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

target_host="${1-Server_1_ip}"
while IFS='=' read key value; do
        case "$key" in
        $target_host) target_ip="$value";;
        Server_port) target_port="$value";;
        esac
done < input
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `sed` variant:

```
sed -n -e'/Server_1_ip=\(.*\)/{s//\1/;h}; /Server_port=\([0-9]*\)/{s// \1/;H;g;s/\n//p;q}' inputfile
```

- `-n` stops normal output,
- apply `-e commands`

  - First find target server, ie. `Server_1_ip=` with a subexpression that remembers the value (assumed its well formed IPv4).  Apply a command block that replaces the pattern space (aka current line) with the saved subexpression and then copies the pattern space to the hold buffer; end command block.
  - Continue looking for port line. Apply command block that removes the prefix leaving the port number; *append* the port to the hold buffer (so now you have `IP newline port` in hold); copy the hold buffer back to pattern space; delete the newline and print result; quit.

Note: GNU and BSD `sed` can vary especially with trying to join lines, ie. `s/\n//`.